# Cómo escribir sobrenombres

Tags: gramática, redacción

Tengo dudas sobre cómo es la forma de escribir un agradecimiento a una persona de nombre Antonio, cuyo sobrenombre es "L". Un compañero afirma que debe ser

> A Antonio << L >> por su amistad.

Sin embargo, creo que está incorrecto. ¿Esta es la forma correcta o debe ser otra?

Comment: Si instalas el teclado "English International," podrás fácilmente llegar a « con Alt (de la mano derecha) [.

Answer (score 7):

Lo que dice tu compañero está *basado en hechos reales*, pero no es correcto tal como nos lo copias. Es decir: es correcto e incluso recomendable usar las llamadas *comillas españolas* cuando el apodo está entre nombre y apellido:

> A Antonio «L» García por su amistad

Como ves, este signo es parecido al `<< >>` que pones en tu mensaje, pero no igual. El problema de las comillas españolas es que no suelen estar en los teclados de los ordenadores, por lo que hoy día no se usan con mucha frecuencia, [pese a ser las recomendadas por la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=comillas). Puedes usar perfectamente las comillas altas en su lugar:

> A Antonio "L" García por su amistad

Igualmente puedes sustituir las comillas por la letra cursiva, recurso cada vez más usado hoy día:

> A Antonio *L* García por su amistad

Sin embargo, si el apodo se escribe en solitario, o bien al principio o final del nombre, [lo adecuado es escribirlo sin más](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/apodos-y-aliasescritura-correcta-559/), a veces separándolo con comas por claridad:

> A Antonio, L, por su amistad

Si en tu caso se deberían usar las comas o no, depende de la naturaleza del apodo. Si es un sobrenombre es decir, se suele usar *además* del nombre, lo habitual es que no se usen:

> Isabel la Católica

Si es un apodo, es decir, se usa habitualmente *en lugar* del nombre, muchas veces sí se usan:

> Leopoldo Alas, Clarín

pero otras no, sobre todo cuando el apodo empieza por un artículo:

> Rafael Álvarez el Brujo

Comment: http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/apodos-y-aliasescritura-correcta-559/

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that if the OP wants to search the internet for codes for the _comillas españolas_we call them guillemets in English (not to be confused with guillemots, they are birds).

Comment: Interesante, @guifa. Voy a cambiar un poco mi respuesta.

Comment: Perdón, tienes razón, él usó las comillas españolas «,» como tú mencionaste. Lo que pasa es que no las tenía en mi teclado.

Comment: ¿Pero entonces debe poner nombre y apellido para colocar el apodo entre ellos o puede poner sólo el nombre y el apodo?

Comment: Puedes poner solo el nombre y el apodo, claro.

Answer (score 1):

Gorpik ha propuesto muchas e interesantes alternativas, pero me gustaría proponer otra [que comenta la RAE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fMYfjJoCHLJYrlZA) en su *Nueva gramática*, epígrafe 12.8l:

> Se suele denominar ALIAS al tipo de seudónimo que algunos individuos emplean como nombre artístico o profesional, pero también como denominación que les atribuye el público: *la Chunga, el Cordobés, la Fornarina*. [...] El término *alias* se puede anteponer en estas construcciones al grupo nominal que introduce: *Sin embargo, el propio Sánchez, tras su captura, los identificó como Rolando de Jesús Sánchez Álvarez, alias el Gordo, y Gilberto Carrillo, alias Quénque* (*Hora* 14/11/2000).

Luego otra opción para lo que quieres expresar es:

> A Antonio, alias L, por su amistad.

Si te fijas, el apodo no necesita en este caso tampoco escribirse ni en cursiva ni entre comillas de ningún tipo.

El significado de la palabra *alias* en este tipo de construcciones es el siguiente:

> **[alias](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1q3Mb6q)**
>
> Del lat. *alias* 'de otro modo'.
>
> 2. adv. Por otro nombre. *Alfonso Tostado, alias el Abulense.*

Se usa pues como un adverbio, antepuesto al seudónimo. En todo caso, la *Gramática* comenta que "se utiliza *alias* [...] en especial entre individuos que viven al margen de la ley", aunque aclara que "estos usos no poseen necesariamente función descalificadora". Es decir, que se puede usar *alias* con cualquier persona que tenga un apodo.